# Incomplete box around selected event in timeline

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, timeline

When linking to a specific event in a post's timeline, e.g. [this one](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/142045/timeline#review_128095) the linked event gets a yellow-brownish box to highlight it. However, the bottom line of that box isn't shown (at least not in the latest Safari and Firefox on macOS Catalina), unless the last (oldest) event is selected. The first (newest) event doesn't even show the top line.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has now been resolved.

Comment: Thanks, it is indeed. However (but I should have mentioned that in the original bug report) it's still awkwardly touching the event type label ('review', 'history'): https://i.stack.imgur.com/99gX9.png

Comment: @Glorfindel they're very close. We should not break them apart, it's cruel. ;)