# Does the date field in the Timeline have a broken link?

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, timeline

Android v.12 Galaxy XCover Pro, with Google app version 13.12.11.23.arm64 in "full site" view...

Further to this question: [Incomplete box around selected event in timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347460/906208), when I select the date in a question's Timeline the highlighted yellow box suggests that it has (or should have) a link or some additional function. But it does nothing that I can see.

Am I missing something?

Bonus question: As above, but a mysterious "S" appears next to some Community Bot's actions - but not all, and they disappear when I click away. What does this "S" signify?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope! This is normal behavior.

The timestamp links change your browser's current address to the most recently-selected link. Copying this link allows you to link to that specific entry in the timeline. Here's an [example for this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/377913/timeline#history_766491dc-32fa-47cc-9b22-6c728eef9cab), which links directly to when you asked it. When you select multiple entries, it retains the highlight on the previous entry. I do not know why *that* behavior exists.

The "S" notation that you mention indicates that events in the timeline that are next to each other occurred at "simultaneous dates" (the "simultaneous dates" text comes from the tooltip when the "S" is hovered over with the mouse). This typically happens for posts deleted by the Community user when the post reaches 6 spam flags (or one spam flag from a moderator), as the Community user applies a lock and then deletes the post at the exact same time. As proof, here's what the timeline looks like for a recently spam-deleted question on this site:

[image: Timeline for a spam deleted question, with the simultaneous "lock" and "Delete" events highlighted]