# What does `S` stand for in the timeline?

Tags: support, edits, timeline

E.g. from https://patents.stackexchange.com/posts/24959/timeline:

[image]

Appeared after clicking on the edit dated Oct 4 at 22:39

Same?

Comment: Considering it was in the suggested edits queue... suggested edit?

Comment: It stands for "simultaneous dates" (cf. [Spevacus's answer to 'Does the date field in the Timeline have a broken link?'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/377914/986753)).

Comment: I like the question, it's short and to the point. Perhaps the closure should be the other way around, but I think the questions are similar enough that one of them should be closed using the other as target.

Comment: @bad_coder I shortened the other question a bit, removed one example, and downsized the images a tad.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[image]

Hovering over the S shows it stands for "simultaneous dates"

Comment: Thanks, makes me wonder [How can I hovering over some text in a webpage in Opera for Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/248738/12202)

Comment: More obvious, but it is also the case in [search results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=stand+for+timeline).